# Does mysqli supports embedded structures?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So, In mysql you can write embedded structures like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `questions` WHERE `type`='foo';");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id`='".$row['id']."'");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Answer id:".$row2['id'];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that in mysqli, using prepare()? 
If I write this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `questions` WHERE `type`=?;");
$stmt->bind_param('s','foo');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($question_id);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id`=?");
     die(var_dump($stmt2)); // bool(false)
}
```

$stmt2 is boolean false, because I didn't closed $stmt. But if I close it, I can't access result data in loop. So, the only way to do it - copy result of $stmt to another variable, do $stmt->close() and then start while() loop? 
Or there is another ways to do it?

Or I don't understand something..:)

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Use a join and order by the question primary key instead:

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT q.*, a.* FROM questions q LEFT JOIN answers a ON (q.id = a.question_id) WHERE q.type = ? ORDER BY q.id");

$stmt->bind_param('s','foo');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($question_id);

$currentQuestion = false;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
     if($currentQuestion !== $question_id){
       $currentQuestion = $question_id;
       // output question or whatever
     }
     // output answers
}
```

The thin you have to be wary of here is if you are returning an assoc array then if the tables share columns (for example both tables might have an `id` column) then you are only going to get one of the values. To avoid this you need to alias the columns which means you have to alias them ALL in the query like:

`SELECT q.id as qid, q.body as qbody, q.type as qtype, a.id as aid, a.body as abody, a.question_id as aqid FROM questions q LEFT JOIN answers a ON (q.id = a.question_id) WHERE q.type = ? ORDER BY qid`

Comment: prodigitalson, I understand that with THIS EXAMPLE I can use join and order by. But sometimes it is necessary to make another query to database while reading results of previous query. Is it possible with mysqli?

Comment: Not with a prepared statement, maybe with a direct execution but im not 100% - its been years since I've used MySQLi. In general disagree with your statement actually, Ive never found this do be the case, there is almost always a better way which will result in fewer queries. But how to go about that is use case specific.